# div content shifts to left as screen size gets reduced

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've provided the html and css. The   is modified by the script.js file which is why it's empty. I want the text to appear at the center even when screen width is reduced. Please help.

HTML:

```
    <section id="page1">
      <div class="welcome">
        <div class="box">
          <img class="mypic" src="img/me.jpg" alt="" srcset="" />
          <h1 id="welcomeText1"></h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

CSS:

```
#page1, #page2, #page3, #page4 {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-left: 2rem;
}
.mypic {
  width: 15rem;
  height: 15rem;
  border-radius: 500px;
}
```

I've provided screenshots below.
Absolute beginner here. =)

At normal width

[image]

On decreasing width

[image]

Comment: add `#welcomeText1  { text-align: center; }`

Comment: worked like charm =)

Comment: When you do `justify-content: center;` it will only align the div/element which is the child of your flexbox. But to align the text in that particular element you need to use `text-align: center; `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `justify-content: center;` it will only align the div/element which is the child of your flexbox.

But to align the text/content in that particular element you need to use `text-align: center;`

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand, you just need to add CSS property to `welcomeText1`:

```css
#page1, #page2, #page3, #page4 {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-left: 2rem;
}
.mypic {
  width: 15rem;
  height: 15rem;
  border-radius: 500px;
}
#welcomeText1{
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid green;
}
```

```html
<section id="page1">
  <div class="welcome">
    <div class="box">
      <img class="mypic" src="img/me.jpg" alt="" srcset="" />
      <h1 id="welcomeText1">Welcome to stackoverflow <br> Welcome</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

(I had you a border to show you)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `text-align: center` for the text.

```
#welcomeText1 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Or if you want to keep the text in that structure, you could decrease the font size when using small screens with media queries.

```
#welcomeText1 {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
}

@media (max-width: 720px) {
    #welcomeText1 {
        font-size: 1.2rem;
    }
}
```